# Building Google V8 libs for windows

Tags: build, libraries

I'm trying to build v8.lib for usage. I've spent two days doing it. So no successful results. How I'm trying to build:

```
tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

It builds withour errors, but no any .lib in directory.
I can only run v8.exe and paste JS code to test it...
How to build libs for my own projects?

Comment: It seems to be to be confirmed via this question.
[How to compile the smallest possible V8 library for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287363/how-to-compile-the-smallest-possible-v8-library-for-windows).

Comment: Git links are outdated. Still cant build libs.

Comment: @SoloMid Having the exact same issue, been two days now. Tried tons of things but with no result. Have you been able to find the answer yet?